# C: Changing the value of a char array with a void function with a pointer as a parameter

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char, void

If I try to print from main (as shown) I get a bunch of weird symbols. If I try to print from func, I get "segmentation fault."

I also have the warning: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

This is part of an assignment, so I can't change main (which is in another file and includes a prototype for func.)

edit: I got it. Using " instead of ' was my problem. I always keep doing that.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   char s[33];
   void func(char *s);

      func(s);
      printf("%s\n", s);
      return 0;
}

void func (char *s){

s[0]="b";
s[1]="o";
s[2]="p";

}
```

Comment: Um, this doesn't even compile.

Answer (score 0):

Mistake 1 : You trying to assign character array instead of character. Use single quotes to assign characters.
Mistake 2 : Function in not called inside main
Mistake 3 : You have declared character array as 'str', but later you refering it as 's'

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is what you intend to do:
Use single quotes to assign characters to `char array` and null terminate the string.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(char *s);
int main(void)
{
   char str[33];

      func(str);
      printf("%s\n", str);
}

void func (char *s){

s[0]='b';
s[1]='o';
s[2]='p';
s[3] = '\0';

}
```